# Finding the most frequent character in a file in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that finds the most common alphabetic character in a file. The function should ignore all characters other than alphabetic.

At the moment I have the following:

```
int most_common(const char *filename)
{
char frequency[26];
int ch = 0;

FILE *fileHandle;
if((fileHandle = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
    return -1;
}

for (ch = 0; ch < 26; ch++)
    frequency[ch] = 0;

while(1){
    ch = fgetc(fileHandle);
    if (ch == EOF) break;

    if ('a' <= ch && ch  <= 'z')
        frequency[ch - 'a']++;
    else if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')
        frequency[ch - 'A']++;
}

int max = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 26; ++i)
  if (frequency[i] > frequency[max])
      max = i;

return max;
}
```

Now the function returns how many times the most frequent letter occurred, not the character itself. I'm a bit lost, as I'm not sure if that's the way this function should look like at all. Does it make sense and how possibly can I fix the problem?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your program seems good. What is exactly your problem? If you want to return the most frequent character, you only have to change the last lines in order to keep track of it in the same time as you register the `max`. I would also recommend to avoid `for/if` statements without curly brackets. This is evil and error prone.

Comment: Joe's answer is good. I just wanted to add that it's better to change `char frequency[26]` to `int frequency[26]`. Or even `long`. Otherwise the code won't work correctly if the input text contains more than 255 identical letters (for instance, 270 `A`s), because the counter will overflow.

Comment: There are lots of alphabetic characters other than A-Z and a-z. If your algorithm isn't intended to handle them, just abend, for example, `if (ch > 127) return -2;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `frequency` is indexed by the character code. So `frequency[0]` is 5, if there have been 5 'a's.

In your code you are assigning the count to `max`, not the character code, so you're returning the count not the actual character.

You need to store both the maximum frequency count and the character code that it referred to.

I would fix this with:

```
int maxCount = 0;
int maxChar = 0;
// i = A to Z
for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i)
{
  // if freq of this char is greater than the previous max freq
  if (frequency[i] > maxCount)
  {
      // store the value of the max freq
      maxCount = frequency[i];

      // store the char that had the max freq
      maxChar = i;
  }
}

// character codes are zero-based alphabet.
// Add ASCII value of 'A' to turn back into a char code.
return maxChar + 'A';
```

Note that I changed `int i = 1` to `int i = 0`. Starting at 1 would mean starting at `B`, which is a subtle bug you might not notice. Also, the loop should terminate at `<= 26`, otherwise you'd miss out `Z` too.

Note the braces. Your braces style (no braces for single-statement blocks) comes *very* highly un-recommended.

Also, `i++` is more common than `++i` in cases like this. In this context it will make no difference, so would advise `i++`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works fine until the function is tested with an empty file. Instead of returning 0 it returns 'A'.

Comment: Somehow you need to find a way to return from your function the information that there is no max character. One way is to return a special number, like `-1` to indicate this. I won't write the code for you! Why not think about setting `maxChar` to a special initial value, so if it never gets changed, you can tell. Or setting a boolean flag in the loop so you know if it ever runs.